# JMeter: Script to compare response kept in an external parameterised file

Tags: jmeter

I have following requirement
1. Keep responses in an external xml file. 
2. Hit the API and compare the response with external response (Kept in xml file. )
3. Also while comparison, I have to ignore dynamic components like ,  etc. 
4. Also I have to ignore sequence of parameters.

Can you please if any such utility/program to do so in JMeter

Thanks in advance

Regards
Vishal Pachpute

Comment: Please clarify pp. 3 & 4 (at least these points), we can't read in your mind.

Comment: 3. Actually while comparison of 2 xml files, I have to ignore the dynamic elements such as trans-id etc. 4. Also while comparison of 2 files, I have to ignore the sequence. e.g. package type may be at 6th line in an external xml file and in actual response it might be at 8th line. So basically to ignore the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it makes more sense to use [XML Schema Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XML_Schema_Assertion). This way you will validate your XML response syntax and structure, elements and attributes, number and order of attributes, data types, etc. but this assertion won't care in the slightest about the content.

You can ask the .xsd schema from the developers, most likely they have it, if not the majority of IDEs can do this, there are even online services.

References:

- [XML Schema Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)